# Javascript Delivery Show Based On Time

Tags: javascript

I am trying to show this condition,

00 - 07 am - show "Today Morning" ||
07 - 19 pm - show "Today Evening" ||
19 - 24 am - show "Tomorrow Morning"

But I guess something is wrong with my code.

```
   <html> 
<head>
    <title>Greeting Message using JavaScript</title> 
</head>
<body>
    <label id="lblGreetings"></label>
</body>

<script>
    var myDate = new Date();
    var hrs = myDate.getHours();

    var greet;

    if (hrs > 07 && hrs <= 19)
        greet = 'Today Evening';
    else if (hrs >= 19 && hrs <= 24)
        greet = 'Tommorow Morning';
    else if (hrs >= 00 && hrs <= 07)
        greet = 'Today Morning';

    document.getElementById('lblGreetings').innerHTML =
        '<b>' + greet + '</b> and welcome to Encodedna.com!';
</script> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var myDate = new Date();
    var hrs = myDate.getHours();

    var greet;

    if (hrs > 07 && hrs <= 19)
        greet = 'Today Evening';
    else if (hrs >= 19 && hrs <= 24)
        greet = 'Tommorow Morning';
    else if (hrs >= 00 && hrs <= 07)
        greet = 'Today Morning';

    document.getElementById('lblGreetings').innerHTML =
        '<b>' + greet + '</b> and welcome to Encodedna.com!';
 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html> 
<head>
    <title>Greeting Message using JavaScript</title> 
</head>
<body>
    <label id="lblGreetings"></label>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Why not using DOMContentLoaded? You could skip including the jquery lib.

Answer (score 0):

Below you can find a simplified version of your code. Keep in mind your statement can be minimised by only check if the `hours` are `lower than` your threshold.

```
var myDate = new Date();
var hrs = myDate.getHours();

var greet;

if (hrs < 7) {
    greet = 'Today Morning';
} else if (hrs < 19) {
    greet = 'Today Evening';
} else {
    greet = 'Tomorrow Morning';
}

alert(greet);
```

Comment: How do I change "Tomorrow Morning" to "Today Morning" after 24?